# LuaLatex: Showing nonexisting errors

Tags: luatex, babel, input-encodings

I am trying to use LuaLatex for printing plots (as PdfLaTeX doesn't have enough memory) but I have a problem with it. I am using TeXLive 2013 with TeXMaker.

I was trying to compile a file once with LuaLaTeX and some errors were shown. I managed to compile that file using PdfLaTeX, however now that I need to use LuaLaTeX again, the same errors are shown with every file I am trying to compile, although they don't have any relation to the first file.

I have tried deleting the `luatex-cache` folder from `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-var`, however the problem persists.

Errors I got:

> ! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence. 
>   \DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\"}{LGR}{
>
> ! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence. 
>   \accdialytika \DeclareTextCompositeCommand

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} 

\begin{document} 
\latintext{Hello!} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! May you please inform the errors?

Comment: Actually, I was using babel in the first file, so something like that appeared:
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence. \DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\"}{LGR}{
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.<argument> �\accdialytika \DeclareTextCompositeCommand
etc

The thing is that the lines that correspond to that file don't exist in all the other files I am trying to compile

Comment: are all your files encoded as utf8? You may press on file - save as and change the encoding. Just a guess, but easy to try.

Comment: And please show as a minimal working example which shows your problem. Are you loading the package `fontenc`?

Comment: Do not use inputenc with luatex (which is I suspect the problem)

Comment: I am using luainputenc with UTF-8, which used to work.
I don't use fontenc, however pdflatex compiles just fine.
The following example doesn't complile, but I think it should:  

    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}  
    \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}  
    \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}  
  
    \begin{document}  
  
    \latintext{Hello!}  
  
    \end{document}

Comment: @whirlwind Don't load `luainputenc`, that's all.

Comment: To me it sounds as if one of the files loaded by babel  contains non-ascii chars but is not utf8 encoded. I suspect an old babel version.  Make sure that your system is really up-to-date. Only with new babel version you can use greek with lualatex.

Comment: If I don't use inputenc or luainputenc, what should I use?
The thing is that this scheme worked until one point, when that error showed up and from then on it keeps appearing whatever file I try to compile, such that the error log of lualatex hasn't been deleted.

Comment: @whirlwind `luainputenc` is only for compatibility with old documents; LuaTeX accepts by default UTF-8 input, there's no need of any special package for the input encoding. Update your TeX distribution. However, a bug has been planted in the last version of `greek.ldf` and the `\fi` on line 73 should be removed.

Comment: I found the problem, thank you! As Ulrike Fischer and egreg suggested, the file that babel is trying to load (greek.ldf) isn't encoded in UTF-8 so the character on that line isn't recognised, so that's what causing the problem and not the cache, which I thought. I'll try updating TeX Live 2013...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue fixed by a package update.